# How can I get the previous page from history in classic ASP?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Is there a way I can get the previous page the user was at in classic ASP?  I am looking for the equivalent of `history.go(-1)` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending upon your needs you may be able to use:

```
Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER");
```

> Returns a string containing the URL of
>   the page that referred the request to
>   the current page using an `<a>` tag. If
>   the page is redirected, `HTTP_REFERER`
>   is empty.

Typically if I need to know where the user came from, though, I would set this explicitly in the querystring or in a form variable.

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion for tracking the prior page value when you hit the new page via "response.redirect"?  http_referrer is empty in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp

Request.ServerVariables ( "HTTP_REFERER" )